# Python Outlook how to handle recall email

Tags: python, email, outlook

My project works on emails in Inbox. When process get a "Recall" email it crashes. Recall email does not have subject attribute. I want to write some error handling. I cannot find method to move email to another folder or delete such email from Outlook.

Currently my Code skip such items using method GetPrevious() but the email is still in Inbox
Do you have any ideas how to make 'recall' email disappear from Inbox folder?

```
    obj_emails = obj_inbox.Items
    obj_email = obj_emails.GetLast()

    if obj_email.MessageClass == 'IPM.Outlook.Recall':
        obj_email = obj_emails.GetPrevious()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for handling or generating recall items. You may consider using a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI. Also you may consider using thied-party components, i.e. wrappers around the low-level API such as Redemption.

Try to play with [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) to make sure recall items can be easily handled (moved or removed).

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Class` property - all OOM objects expose it. For the `MailItem`, it will be 43 (`OlObjectClass.olMail`). For `ReportItem` - 46 (`OlObjectClass.olReport`)

Comment: How can the `Class` help with handling recall items in Outlook?

Comment: The OP need to filter out report items to avoid accessing the properties not exposed by `ReportItem`.

Comment: This is not a report item as far as I remember. The report item has the `IPM.Report` message class.

Comment: "IPM.Outlook.Recall" messages are represented by the `MailItem` object in OOM. But it will raise an exception when some properties are accessed (e.g. Body, but not Subject). The only way to check for a message like that is though the MessageClass property.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to point out. It is not a report item in Outlook and the OP does it right.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion.
I do not want to complicate the code so I use MessageClass property to catch recall email. Next information will be sent to team to remove such email.

```html
if obj_email.MessageClass == 'IPM.Outlook.Recall':
            raise Exception(f"There is a recall email in mailbox. Please remove it from inbox.")
```